# Collecting rationals with sympy collect_const

Tags: sympy, simplification

Sympy (ver. 1.1.1) documentation of [`collect_const`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/simplify/radsimp.html#collect_const) says that using the `Numbers=False` option, "no Float or Rational will be collected". This makes you think that rationals are normally collected by `collect_const`, but they don't seem to be:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> collect_const(2*x - 2*y - 2*z, 2)
2*(x - y - z)
>>> collect_const(x/2 - y/2 - z/2, 1/2)
x/2 - y/2 - z/2
```

Am I missing something?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think is a little **bug**. The argument `Numbers` doesn't seem to work well with the arithmetic operator "/". From your example:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> collect_const(x/2 - y/2 - z/2, 1/2, Numbers=False)
x/2 - y/2 - z/2
>>> collect_const(x/2 - y/2 - z/2, 1/2, Numbers=True)
x/2 - y/2 - z/2
```

It doesn't seem to affect the expression. However, if we change "/2" for ".5*" the result is quite different:

```
>>> collect_const(.5*x - .5*y - .5*z, 1/2, Numbers=False)
.5*x - .5*y - .5*z
>>> collect_const(.5*x - .5*y - .5*z, 1/2, Numbers=True)
.5*(x - y - z)
```

Anyway, I've created an `Issue` on [Github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13107).